# Идея для ускорения скорости загрузки страниц.

Tags: html

Сидел как-то, сёрфил по страничкам, и пришла идея. Сильно не пинайте, я может сильно отстал от жизни. А что если, при первой загрузке страницы, все картинки и другие объекты сохраняются на компьютере, и последующая загрузка картинок идёт напрямую к компьютера? Разве не ускорится ли загрузка страниц?

Comment: Увеличьте размер кэша браузера и все проблемы решаться. Зачем изобретать велосипед? Как изменять размер кэша спросите на: http://user.hashcode.ru/

Comment: @Дмитрий Алексеевич, не нужно удалять текст вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поумолчанию все браузеры итак сохраняют всю информацию (картинки,видео,swf,и даже скрипты) в специальную папку она называется "Кэш"

Comment: Кеш быстро забивается

Comment: Зависит от размера кэша и количества страниц))

Comment: Правильно @Rules сказал

Answer (score 2):

Дмитрий, когда вы, как вы выразились, «сёрфите» по страничкам, они (их исходный код и медиа-файлы) уже находятся на вашем компьютере.  Вы лишь открываете их с помощью браузера. А вот как выбранный вами браузер поведет себя при попытке повторно обратиться к файлу, который уже был загружен, зависит от настроек данного браузера. Повлиять на них (настройки) со стороны сайта невозможно. Но скорее всего, ваш браузер тратит время не на повторную загрузку уже существующего файла, а сверяется, что файл, к которому он пытается обратиться на сайте, уже есть в хранилище («кэше», как верно подметил [@Rules](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1267/rules)).